# Flutter: markNeedsLayout and markNeedsPaint are never causing the RenderBox to be repainted

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a callback, that is happening when the user drags down a RenderBox - the callback is triggered - the RenderBox is in a MultiChildRenderObjectWidget.

I need to changee the position of the child and then mark it with `markNeedsPaint()` to be repainted - but this is never happening.

This is the snipped from my code:

```
final RenderObject? renderObject = _myWidgetKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject();
          renderObject?.visitChildren((child) {
            if (child is RenderTimelineItem) {
              child._position = 2;
              child.markNeedsPaint();
              renderObject.markNeedsPaint();

            }
          });
```

In the Debugger, I see, that `_position` value is updated to 2, and I also see that `"NEEDS-PAINT"` Flag is set to child and renderObject.

Is there a specific function to make the repaint running immediately?

Thanks

***EDIT:***

The thing I want to do is, I want to drag down this appointment with starting 07:10 to the second resource group.
I am editing the [dynamic_timeline 0.1.2](https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_timeline) package.
I already implemented horizontal dragging for the appointment in the same resource. When the user is pressing ctrl and starts dragging, the appointment should be able to be dragged down to the next resource group.

[image: ExampleScreenshot]

Comment: do you need to touch low level `RenderBox`es? what do you want to achieve actually? cannot you use widgets like `CustomMultiChildLayout` / `Flow` etc?

Comment: @pskink: I have edited the question info with a screenshot of a example. Please check pub.dev

Comment: and you are changing `RenderDynamicTimeline`?

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

in the `Dragcontroller` callback in `RenderTimelineItem` i have to give the position to `RenderTimelineItem` and to its parent (`DynamicTimelineParentData`) and then `markParentNeedsLayout()` - here example:

```
  void _onUpdateUpDownDrag(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    _position = 2;
    parentData?.position = 2;
    markParentNeedsLayout();

  }
```